# C#-sql update code. Too many columns in acess database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

I have an c# program that update 2 columns, in each table in my access database file(.mdb). Columns that I'm updatnig are short string type, I am also changing their size to 255, before updating. I have 15 files, my code is working for first 7 dbs, and crash on 8-th file. I am updating each code separately, and it crash about in the middle of database

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Record is too large.'
>
> Query string that is crashing :
> UPDATE CARTE SET SYMBOLE = 'AGLX19.A8E', SYMBOLE2 = 'AWLX19.A8E;@P516.@PQ;@P517.@PQ;@P518.@PQ;@P519.@PQ' WHERE CODE = '2862411';

```
private void UpdateSYMBOLEinDatabase(string tableName, string code)
    {

        if (symboleMdb[0] == "")
            return;

        string queryString = "UPDATE " + tableName +
                            " SET SYMBOLE = '" + symboleMdb[0] + "', SYMBOLE2 = '" + symboleMdb[1] + "' " +
                             "WHERE CODE = '" + code + "';";

        if (symboleMdb[1] == "")
            queryString = queryString.Replace(", SYMBOLE2 = ''", "");

        using (OleDbConnection connectionInput = new OleDbConnection(connectionStringInput))
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connectionInput))
        {
            connectionInput.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I haved checked sql string carefully (also in online checker).
I had also search on google's and found that this error, is probably connected with too many columns in my db, actually when I am opening db file, there is about 220 columns. But when I am counting columns programmaticly it shows that there is about 878 columns(before/after changing length of short string type in columns). For others tables it shows correct count.

I found that copying table, may help. But actually I also can't do that.

```
private void CopyDeleteCopyDeleteQuery(string tableName)
    {
        string queryString = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + "O"+
                            " AS (SELECT * FROM " + tableName +
                            " WHERE CODE='0801733');";
        using (OleDbConnection connectionInput = new OleDbConnection(connectionStringInput))
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connectionInput))
        {
            connectionInput.Open();                
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.'
>
> Query string :
> CREATE TABLE CARTEO AS (SELECT * FROM CARTE WHERE CODE='0801733');

Comment: Please try to limit your question to one problem. Your syntax for copying tables is incorrect, MS Access uses `SELECT ... INTO` to copy queries to tables, instead of `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

The limit for fields is 2kB (excluding Memo and OLE. With ~220 columns fields, you are likely to be hitting that limit.

You should normalize the table, or convert some columns to Memo fields.